# JUnit tests failing in Jenkins with IllegalStateException

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, junit5

I'm running some JUnit5 tests in Jenkins, using a freestyle job and a Jenkins pipeline. These tests run fine using gradlew locally.

The pipeline groovy script (Jenkinsfile) uses

```
sh './gradlew clean test'
```

The code checks out fine and I see the Welcome to Gradle 5.5.1! message

Then, all of the tests which run fine locally with gradlew clean test fail with:

```
15:50:22 
uk.co.motests.mfldirect.tests.UploadDataTest > 
dropDownsAreDisplayed() FAILED
15:50:22     java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

Any idea where / how to start debugging this?  This is literally the first time I've tried to run using a groovy pipeline script.

I'm posting this in the hope there is a common, beginners mistake that crops up frequently.  I can post further details of the groovy file if required.

Comment: You can open the Gradle project using an IDE, so that debug will be easier. If using Eclipse (get the most recent version), you can "import as Gradle project.."

Comment: since a junit test is failing, it makes more sense to understand first why it fails on a DEV machine. (leaving Jenkins and the pipelines out of the picture..)

Comment: @Daniele apologies - I thought I had added that they run fine locally - which they do - but I had not. Sorry

Comment: well if tests always fail on the jenkins box, something can be missing there- you can obviously add more logging and check the log output- expecially where the code is throwing.

Answer (score 0):

- To print tests' stdout and stacktrace, enable Gradle INFO logging with `sh './gradlew clean test -i'`
- To view DEBUG logging use `sh './gradlew clean test -d'`

All this data is already present in `./build/test-results/test/*.xml` so you could browse the workspace of the failed Jenkins job.